# Why docker's rabbitMQ container doesn't start with (almost) similar commands?

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

> docker run -it --rm --name rabbitmq -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672
>   rabbitmq:3-management

that command starts rabbit good and it let me see the UI via 
http://localhost:15672/#/users

> docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit -e
>   RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=aaa -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=aaa -p 5672:5672 -p
>   15762:15762 rabbitmq:3-management

this one doesn't let me enter the UI. Why this happens?

I even tried

> docker run -it --rm --name some-rabbit -p 5672:5672 -p 15762:15762
>   rabbitmq:3-management

with no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems you have a typo in the second command. It's `-p 15762:15762` and it should be `-p 15672:15672`

Comment: @b0gusb you're a saver, tnx a lot!

Comment: @b0gusb , please put in your comment in the answer section :-)